# Framework for consuming REST services from .NET

Tags: .net, mono, rest

I am looking for a framework for communicating to rest services.

The framework must be:

- .NET 4+ Compatible
- Mono Compatible
- Minimizes boilerplate code

As a side note the server actually runs NancyFX and I do have control of the server for getting meta information out about the REST API it exposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) matches all the criteria.

Coding is straight forward:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value");
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); 
request.AddHeader("header", "value");
```

Supports:

- .NET 3.5+
- Silverlight 5
- Windows Phone 8
- Mono
- MonoTouch
- Mono for Android